# i am trying to write a code to randomly choose a girl name that 3 times has been chosen by random

Tags: python

I want to write a code that receives several names from the user and randomly selects one of them and puts it in a list and repeats this until the number of one name in the list reaches 3, then it Display the name as the final selection. please help me

```
import random

list_of_names = []

def name():
    names = input("please insert names and then say 'done' to end: ")
    if names == "done" or names == "Done":
        print("thank you for using our app!")
        pass
    else:
        list_of_names.append(names)
        name()

name()

random_list = []

def random_name():
    choice = random.choice(list_of_names)
    random_list.append(choice)
    for i in random_list:
        if random_list.count(i) == 3:
            print("the winner is " + i)
            break
        else:
            random_name()

random_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

save those user input names into an array and use `random.choice(list)`. this can be used to choose a random item from a sequence. Here It can be a list, tuple, string, or any iterable like range.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by other users, you should post your code (even if incorrect) instead of throwing open ended questions.
In any case, a simple solution could be the following:

```
import random

my_counter = {}

def update_counter(names, max_occurrences=3):
    for name in names:
        my_counter[name] = my_counter.get(name, 0) + 1
        print(my_counter)
        if my_counter[name] == max_occurrences:
            return name

while True:
    i = input("Please enter the names (space separated)")
    name = update_counter(random.choice(i.split(" ")))
    if name is not None:
        break   

print("Most common name is " + name)
```

The `Counter` object simply allows to keep track of the occurences of each name, and the entered names must be space separated. You could use a `collections.Counter` to avoid writing the `update_counter` yourself, but this is a more self contained solution if you are learning.